# steps to pull/download .apk file in jenkins from bitbucket code

Tags: java, android, jenkins

May I know the steps to pull the code from bitbucket that is pushed by the developers and download it as .apk. So that I dont wait for the apk file from the developers

Comment: You "cannot download code as apk". You should compile code and it depends on hoe project organized. If devs uses gradle it would be something like ```./geadlew app:assembleDebug```

Comment: I am not sure about that. But one of other team, clicks on project in jenkins which gives all the details like committed code, logs and downloads .apk to your system from the code pushed and committed to bitbucket

Comment: It is possible if jenkins compile code. And it should. But how to compile depends on project which you try yo build